# Change image on click - React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So for example this is my view:

```
<div>
  <img src='../../minus.png' />
</div>
```

Now I want to make that on each click the image changes from `plus.png` to `minus.png`.

So, click once: `minus.png => plus.png`, click again: `plus.png => minus.png`, and so on. How can I make this?

Comment: Post the code you already tried and we will fix it

Comment: I haven't tried anything.. really newbie in React :(( Sorry.. :((

Comment: You can't, it seems others can. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be achieved with a simple toggle handler:

```js
const imagesPath = {
  minus: "https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/131484/isolated/preview/a432fa4062ed3d68771db7c1d65ee885-minus-inside-circle-icon-by-vexels.png",
  plus: "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/glypho-generic-icons/64/plus-big-512.png"
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: true
  }
  toggleImage = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ open: !state.open }))
  }

  getImageName = () => this.state.open ? 'plus' : 'minus'

  render() {
    const imageName = this.getImageName();
    return (
      <div>
        <img style={{maxWidth: '50px'}} src={imagesPath[imageName]} onClick={this.toggleImage} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Edit**
Note that I passed a function parameter for `setState` because my new state depends on the old state. You can read more about it in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#how-do-i-update-state-with-values-that-depend-on-the-current-state)

Comment: Upvoted for callback version of setState in this scenario

Comment: @Chris Thanks, When it bites you once you'll never forget :) you think i should write a note of this in the answer?

Comment: Yes, why not. Anytime you are setting a new state which is based off the old state, use callback version ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code on button click change the condition to render the img src:

```
    import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Card, CardImg, CardBody, Button } from "reactstrap";
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loginState: true
    };
  }

  render() {
    let sessonState;
    let imgurl;
    if (this.state.loginState) {
      sessonState = "Logged In";
      imgurl = "https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300";
    } else {
      imgurl = "https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300";
      sessonState = "Logged Out";
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Session {sessonState}!!</h1>
        <br />
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-4">
              <Card className="shadow">
                <CardImg top width="100%" src={imgurl} alt="Card image cap" />
                <CardBody>
                  <Button
                    className="shadow-sm btn "
                    onClick={() => {
                      this.setState({
                        loginState: false
                      });
                      console.log(`${imgurl}`);
                    }}
                  >
                    Button
                  </Button>
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Bulbs.css';

function Bulb(){

    const bulboff = require('../assets/BulbOff.png');
    const bulbon = require('../assets/BulbOn.png');
    const images = {bulboff,bulbon};
    const [img, setImg] = useState(false);

    const imgChangeHandler = () => {
        if(!img) {
            setImg(true);
        }else{
            setImg(false)
        }
    };
    return(
        <div>
            <img src={!img ? bulboff : bulbon } alt='bulb-off' onClick={imgChangeHandler}/>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Bulb;
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this is inside the render function:

```
<div>
  <img onClick={() => {this.setState({clicked: true})} 
       src={'../../' + (this.state.clicked ? 'plus' : 'minus') + '.png'}} />
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing one `}` as the closing?